# i got a "blocked by CORS policy" without even making a request

Tags: javascript, npm

Im trying to import a library in a JS file and this is my firt time i do it in frontend js
i required a package many times in node.js but in frontend js i always got " blocked by cors policy
and this is my code
i create a package.json file and install lodash using npm but i cant require it

[cors error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P70MW.png)

[js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqFua.png)

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Z2J.png)

Comment: How do you think the browser is supposed to load the JS file without making a request for it?

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about not posting pictures of text.